# Fill an empty data.table in R by columns

Tags: r, data.table

Is there any way to fill a **completely** empty `data.table`  in R? I have to fill a `data.table` and columns are given by a function called in a loop. I don't know how many columns will be created or what length they will be before launching the function but I do know that all will be the same length.

My aproach is to create an empty data.table and fill it within the loop. But this does not work either because I cannot append columns to empty `data.table` or beacuse I cannot insert rows properly. Check the toy example below (for the sake of simplicity let's avoid the `for` bucle)

```
 f <- someFunction() # just imagine that returns c(1,2,3)

 # this does not work. fails with error msg:  Cannot use := to add columns to a null data.table (no columns), currently
 dt <- data.table()
 dt[, c("b", "c") := list(f(), f())]

 # this actually work. But creates a 0 row data.table which cannot be filled latter
 dt <- data.table(a = numeric() )
 dt[, c("b", "c") := list(numeric(), numeric())]
 dt[, c("b", "c") := list(f(), f())] # no rows are added

 # this workaround works but is ugly as hell 
 dt <- data.table(a = rep(NA, length(f())) )
 dt[, c("b", "c") := list(f(), f())]
 dt[, a := NULL]
```

So Is there any elegant/efficient way of approaching this

Comment: Have you considered starting by storing the data in a list that you convert to a data.table at the end.

Comment: `f <- function() c(1,2,3); 
L <- list(f(), f()); 
setDT(L); 
setnames(L, c("b", "c"))`

Comment: @snoram I have considered It but `data.table(list)` fill the `data.table` by rows and transposing does not work properly. @jogo solution seem to work fine!

Comment: @DavidArenburg please read the whole question. In the example I am using `c("b", "c")` for simplicity but is actually generated within a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
library("data.table")   

f <- function(x) c(1,2,3)

dt <- as.data.table(lapply(11:13, f))
setnames(dt, c("a", "b", "c"))
```

The `lapply()` is doing the loop you mentioned in your question.